# NSAlert Input Box, Validating NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsalert

I've run into a couple of topics that discuss an input box using **NSAlert** like the following.

```
- (NSString *)input: (NSString *)prompt defaultValue: (NSString *)defaultValue {
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText: prompt
                                 defaultButton:@"OK"
                               alternateButton:@"Cancel"
                                   otherButton:nil
                     informativeTextWithFormat:@""];
    NSTextField *input = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 24)];
    [input setStringValue:defaultValue];
    [alert setAccessoryView:input];
    NSInteger button = [alert runModal];
    if (button == NSAlertDefaultReturn) {
        [input validateEditing];
        return [input stringValue];
    } else if (button == NSAlertAlternateReturn) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

So you can insert a textbox just like you do with **AlertView** in **iOS**.  But how can you validate the text field value to enable and disable the default button?  iOS has **(BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView** to let you validate the input.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

set

```
input.delegate=self;
```

and then implement the following methods

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification

you can validate here